# Apache Nutch Crawler - Crawl new injected URLs in existing table only

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, stormcrawler

I have to crawl some URLs via Nutch. For this, I have to provide seed URLs every time. Hence they are injected every time in the same table. Now, as time is passing, the database is going to increase and in generate phase, it looks for all URLs that takes time. Is there some way to instruct Nutch to crawl new injected URLs only and do not look into the table (for old URLs).
Or is there some better approach for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (assumed that "table" stands for "WebTable" used by Nutch 2.x to persist crawled web pages in one of the supported storage back-ends, HBase, etc.): the generator marks fetch lists by a batch-ID, see the script `bin/crawl` for details how batch-IDs are used. It's an arbitrary but unique string, not too long as there are length limits in some of the storage-backend (see the gora-*-mapping.xml). To skip the generation step, you could just use any other tool to mark the freshly injected URLs with a custom batch-ID and then call `fetch`, `parse`, `updatedb`, `index` using this ID.
2. (in case it's about Nutch 1.x) there is a tool `freegen` which takes a list of URLs (a text file) and creates a segment from it. Then call `fetch`, `parse`, `updatedb`, `index` passing as parameter the path of the created segment.

Comment: Thanks, sir, I am using Nutch 2.x with Hbase backend. I was also thinking so as you guided. I was thinking in another way. Update injector code a little bit to mark the injected URLs at that time. It will also make possible to skip a phase (generator) completely. Is there any issue in this approach ?

Comment: Probably not. "skip a phase (generator) completely" - yes, if you do not want to follow links and there is no need to (automatically) re-crawl pages after some time.